# What is this floating green light in Vah Medoh?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

In my game, just inside the entrance to Vah Medoh, slightly above head level and before the column of rising air, there's a greenish column of light ([video](https://photos.app.goo.gl/T1FUBoBC7rt48p8CA), [image](https://photos.app.goo.gl/6dUr7bYHmc28tSju6)).

It appears fixed in space relative to the dungeon - I can look at it from different angles, etc. It seems like maybe it's only there at night, leading to some speculation that it might be a weird glitchy copy of the light from Mount Satori, but I'd really like to know for sure before I beat the boss, given that afterward I won't be able to get back in.

Comment: That sure does look like the light from Mount Satori. It’s very intriguing as to why it’s showing up in Vah Medoh

Comment: Is this on switch/wiiu or cemu? If you're using the latter some bugs are to be expected, but I haven't seen anything texture or resource related in terms of bugs on the official hardware versions.

Comment: That *really* reminds me of the Zelda memory spots.  IIRC there is a memory set in Vah Medoh, but it shouldn't be using that game mechanic.

Comment: @ConnorLSW This is a disc on the Wii U.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wherever this light is coming from, it is a glitch, and has nothing to do with the dungeon at all.

As for what it *might* be, the animation is far too fast for it to be the light from Satori Mountain, and comparing it to the updrafts, it has a similar speed to that (although the more magical appearance obviously shows that this isn't an updraft).

The game is known to experience a variance of graphical glitches, across different platforms, so it's not entirely unexpected, but at the very least it's not game-breaking.